# Delete duplicates and leave one

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below to delete a row if it is duplicate but I want it to leave one of the rows and it is currently deleting all the info of the duplicate rows.

for example, in column B I have the company names and there are some duplicates. I would like to delete all the rows for one and leave the other. Currently it deletes them both,

thanks!

```
Sub ShowandDeleteDuplicateRows()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Long

lRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = Range("B4", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

    For Each cell In rng1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng1, cell.Value) > 1 Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next cell
    For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
```

Comment: You didn't fix the `Cells(i, 3)` from your last question btw.

Comment: Or accept a previous answer as requested.

Comment: Why not user `RemoveDuplicates` feature already built into Excel?

Comment: Use `CountIF` and your variable `i` in the range to test each cell as you loop from the bottom to the top, when you get to the last colored cell, the count will be equal to 1 and will not delete. But since you are coloring all the duplicates the same color you will only keep the top colored cell. If you are going to use the cell color, you will have to have different colors for each duplicate, or delete the duplicates using what Scott commented.